# Webrtc error while initiating addIceCandidate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, signalr, webrtc

I am trying to initiate peer to peer connection in webrtc. I am using signalr as signaling server. I am getting error in all the browser when adding ice candidate. Below is the error and line of code. Please let me know how can i fix this.

Error in Firefox:

> InvalidStateError: No remoteDescription.

Error in Chrome:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on
>   'RTCPeerConnection': Error processing ICE candidate

Code:

```
if (signal.ice) {
       console.log(signal.ice);
       peerConnections.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.ice)).catch(errorHandler.message);
}
```

Comment: Here is a problem that is almost the same as yours, and a solution has been provided, please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57257449/12884742

Comment: Did you solve the issua?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build a new ice candidate object. Just adding signal.ice as ice candidate is enough. Here is the example from the [official webrtc guide](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/peer-connections)

```
signalingChannel.addEventListener('message', async message => {
    if (message.iceCandidate) {
        try {
            await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(message.iceCandidate);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Error adding received ice candidate', e);
        }
    }
});
```